# Is the eslint override overrides all the rules if the rules section is blank?

Tags: eslint, typescript-eslint

I have a .eslint.json file extending one from the parent folder like below.

```
{
  "extends": ["../../.eslintrc.json"],
  "ignorePatterns": ["!**/*"],
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["*.ts", "*.tsx", "*.js", "*.jsx"],
      "rules": {}
    },
    {
      "files": ["*.ts", "*.tsx"],
      "rules": {"@typescript-eslint/no-namespace": "off", "@typescript-eslint/prefer-namespace-keyword": "off"}
    }
  ]
}
```

But none of the rules are applied and no errors/warning are reported when run even though there are errors/warnings.

Is the overrides block with the blank rules the problem ?